# Back button still works after logout in Safari with Django website

Tags: python, django, https, safari, browser-cache

I am building a website with Django that handles sensitive data. My website has a logout button that logs the user out and redirects the browser to the login page. When using Safari version 14.1.1, I am able to click the back button in the browser after being logged out and I am returned to the previous page which contains private data. From my understanding, this doesn't seem to be a Django issue, rather Safari is storing content so it does not have to make another request to the server. I have tried a couple of methods to stop caching including:

```
@cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True, no_store=True)
def some_method(request):
    #do some stuff
```

and:

```
@never_cache
def some_method(request):
     #do some stuff
```

and finally I tried manually changing the request headers with:

```
response["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
response["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response["Expires"] = "0"
```

Also, my views are annotated with `@login_required(redirect_field_name="/somelink")`.
Some of my research suggested that this may not be a cache issue but rather a browser history issue but I'm not sure. It is also worth nothing that Chrome has given me no issues and when I click back button after logout it does not show what the previous user was viewing. Any ideas how I can disable the browser back button after logout in Safari? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you said: If safari just saves the previous page, you can not control that behavior with django-side caching.
You can simply reload the page to check it or use the network monitor. You could as well use a background js that permanently checks for auth and redirects as soon as the session expires - but I guess thats more of a hacky way